# Parse server dashboard not working windows

Tags: android, windows, cmd, dashboard, parse-server

I'm using the parse dashboard at https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard on windows and the cmd prompt says "The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/", but when i go to that url in the browser it says the site cant be reached.

Answer (score 3):

http://0.0.0.0:4040 doesn't work. Windows needs to use localhost.